# Facing issue with SSH in amazon linux after having separate partion for /home

Tags: linux

Having issue wih SSH after launching an instance from image having separate partion for  /home.I found that the new keypair created during server launch doesnot seems to add into authorized keys in /home/ec2-user/.ssh.

Note: I have implemented CIS in the image from which I try to launch new server

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have an image that works just fine. When you add the /home partition, you are unable to use the ssh keys to log in as the ec2-user. Is that correct?

As I recall, the ec2-user's home directory is /var/priv/ec2-user. To move that directory to /home, you need to ensure a few non-obvious things.

1) Copy ALL files and subdirectories, preserving permissions, from /var/priv to /home.
2) Make sure the home directory changes in /etc/passwd from /var/priv to /home
3) If you are running SELinux, you need to set the SELinuc context for /home and /home//.ssh.
4) Restorecon -Rv /home; restorecon -Rv /home/ec2-user, restorecon -Rv /home/user/.ssh

If your permissions are not correct, your keys will not work.

I would recommend having 2 or 3 terminals open on this machine, just in case you mess something up, you can undo what you did.

Also, make sure your root user can `su - ec2-user` and you can get to the home directory.

Comment: Thankyou Scottie H. For your info..I explain my case in brief. I have launched amazon ec2 instance and implement CIS in the server.As per reccomendation I make separate partion for home. I just take an image of this server for future use. In my case when I try to launch server from the image, the keypair that I created during server launch doesnot add to /home/.ssh/authorizedkeys. It only have the key that I used to launch the server for CIS implementation.It would be great If you give me the answer in brief. If you have any question Dont hesitate to ask or comment.

Comment: Can you log in as ec2-user? Is the issue with the ssh keys?

Comment: Yes I can ssh as ec2-user  but with the help of  old key....but the new key  which I created  for new server doesnot added to the /home/.ssh/authorizedkeys so I cannot use it to ssh.If you need any further info please dont hesitate to comment

Comment: When this happens, I just add the new key manually. Do you know how to do that?  You can use <code>ssh-copy-id</code> but I have had trouble with that command. To me, it's just easier to add it manually.

Comment: Yes it works manually after adding key. Is there any other way to trouble shoot the issue .. Whenever I launch server from the image I have to use the same old key and the new key doesnot make any sense? do you have any idea on this? Do CIS implementation on the image cause any issue?

Comment: I would add the new key to authorized keys and make a new image.   
Do you have a userdata script? You can also have that add the new key.

Comment: you mean to remove the oldkey and replace it with new keypair? I dont habe any userdata script.

Comment: Yes, but make sure you can log in _before_ removing the old key.  
When you instantiate the new VM, can you just use the new key?

Comment: Apology..Cant get your point..could you eloborate briefly?

Comment: When you create a VM in AWS, you have to specify your SSH Key pair. Does your new key pair appear when you make a new VM? If so, try using that.

Comment: There lies a problem ..when I create a VM the new key pair I specify doesnot alpear in ec2-user. I have to ssh using the old key which I have used to launch VM for CIS implementation.

Comment: Do you create the VM from a snapshot? That would probably explain the issue.

Comment: Yes..the image have seperate /home snapshot along with separate partion for /var /tmp /var/tmp /var/log and /var/log/audit.Does the separate partion for /home have impact on this issue?

Comment: Yes, since that is where your certificates are stored. Try adding the cert manually, then making a new snapshot of the /home partition. Then, make a VM with the new snapshot.

Comment: Thankyou Scottie!!! Let me try  this

Comment: could you  please tell me about which certificate are you mention here?

Comment: The public key from your new key-pair should go into /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys. Then, make a new snapshot of the /home volume.